# Volume of double cosets $BwB$

Tags: gr.group-theory, p-adic-groups, buildings

In Macdonald's book "Spherical functions on a group of $p$-adic type", Prop. (3.1.7), it is stated that if $w=w_1\dots w_r$ is a reduced word for $w\in W$ (the affine Weyl group), and if $q(w)=(BwB:B)$ (here $B$ is the standard Iwahori subgroup), then $q(w)=q(w_1)\dots q(w_r)$.

I don't understand the proof. The proof is by induction on the length of $w$: If $\alpha$ is a simple (affine) root, and $w\in W$, are such that $l(w_\alpha w)>l(w)$ then $Bw_\alpha wB=Bw_\alpha BBwB$. Since $w_\alpha\ne w$ the cosets $BwB$ and $Bw_\alpha B$ are disjoint, and therefore $q(w_\alpha w)=q(w_\alpha)q(w)$.

My question is how the fact that the cosets $BwB$ and $Bw_\alpha B$ are disjoint implies $q(w_\alpha w)=q(w_\alpha)q(w)$.

Edit: Note that it is not true in general that if $G$ is a group and $B$ is a subgroup, and $BxB$ and $ByB$ are disjoint, then $(BxByB:B)=(BxB:B)(ByB:B)$. It is easy to see that if $BxB=\cup x_iB$ and $ByB=\cup y_iB$ (disjoint unions) then $BxByB=\cup x_iy_jB$, but it could be that this union is not a disjoint union.

Comment: The fact that they are disjoint implies that the elements of the product can be written uniquely as a product of elements of the two double cosets.

Comment: @user43326–That’s not true as written: $wbb^{-1}s=ws$.

Comment: I meant, the left (or right, but fix one direction) cosets $gB$ 's in the product can be written uniquely as products of left cosets.  Sorry.

Comment: @user43326-- I'm not sure I understand your statement. What needs to be proved is that, in the notation above, if $x_iy_jB=x_uy_vB$, then $x_i=x_u$ and $y_j=y_v$. Do you see why this is true?

Comment: No, I am saying that with your hypothesis, we have $x_iB=x_uB$ and $y_jB=y_vB$.

Comment: @user43326— It’s equivalent. Can you prove?

Comment: I think that the spirit of the argument is that $y_j = u w$, where $u$ lies in an appropriate product of positive affine root groups made negative by $w$, and that $w_\alpha$ leaves any such root group positive—but I'm not able to flesh this out yet.

Comment: @LSpice--- I think this works, thanks! I'll try to write the complete argument and post it as an answer.